# How to create Login page in MVC 5 using session ID (database first approach)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, session-variables, session-cookies

I am new to MVC. I want to create login page using session ID so that i can check that ID in each controller and each method in same controller.And is there any requirement of cookie? If yes, then please help me for this using database first approach.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check for succesfull login

```
var x = users.User.where(x=>x.username==m.username && x.password==m.password)
```

2) Assign the Primary Key(usually) to a session say

Session["UserId"]=x.UserID;

3)Check in the ActionResult

```
public actionResult xyz()
{
   if(Session["UserId"]!=null)
// Do something
}
```

4) But using sessions isn't the best approach